# Are homebrew packages static libraries or dynamic?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I was using the SDL2 library I installed with homebrew. I was just wondering if the libraries I linked were statistic or dynamic and how to tell with these package managers.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew installs both libraries for dynamic and static linkage. It installs also the useful utility `sdl2-config`. Run

```
sdl2-config --cflags --static-libs
```

- **--cflags** Print the compiler flags that are necessary to compile a program  or  library  that uses SDL.
- **--static-libs** Print the linker flags that are necessary to statically link a  program  that  uses SDL.

If you have not linked SDL like `--static-libs` showed, you have linked the shared SDL library.

FYI A library can not be dynamic, it is either a shared or a static library, for either dynamic (at runtime) or static (at compile time) link respectively.